# Installing cminpack package in Msys2

Tags: msys2, pacman-package-manager

I have Portable Msys2.
I mean to install `cminpack`.
As I understand, https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mingw-w64-cminpack/ means such package is available. I expected then that the package shows up in the list of available packages, but

```
$ pacman -Ss minpack
```

gave no results.

**Did I infer correctly that the package should show up as available in this list?**

I also tried

```
$ pacman -Qs minpack
```

which gave no results.
(As I understand, any package listed in `pacman -Qs` should also be listed in `pacman -Ss`, so it was useless at this point).

Having concluded that a package being listed in [this search list](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?K=mingw-w64) possibly does not imply it is available for msys2, I checked

```
$ pacman -Ss <pkg>
```

for a few other packages in that list. Some effectively gave no results.

Thus the question

**How can I be certain if a package is available for msys2?**

(If and when I am sure about that, I guess `pacman -S <pkg>` would install it).

See also [this](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got mixed between msys2 pacman and arch linux `pacman`.  What you have linked is an AUR repository for arch linux, *not* MSYS2.  The utility used `pacman` is taken over from arch linux, but that is all.

To search package for a packages within your repositories you really can use `pacman -Ss <package_name>`. If you can't find your package that means that within the installed repositories there is no such package.

If you can't find it you can always check the web: [search within msys2 packages](https://packages.msys2.org/search).  If that is not enough you can do that search within all generated package MSYS2 history: [packages at msys2 repositories](http://repo.msys2.org/).

I have check the repositories for your `mingw-w64-cminpack` package and that is *not* available for msys2.  You would have to cross-compile it yourself.

Comment: But why would the package be called *mingw64* if it is not available for mingw64?
Take for instance https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mingw-w64-agrum/
Would it be only available as source, to be compiled by the user?

Comment: @sancho.s The *mingw64* name only defines that it is a *MinGW* (Minimalist GNU for Windows) - the cross-compiler. It does not imply that it is compatible with MSYS2 (https://github.com/msys2) environment..  To quote the wiki: MSYS2 is an independent rewrite of MSYS, a (command-line) shell for development usage, and based on modern Cygwin (POSIX compatibility layer) and MinGW-w64 (from "MinGW-builds"), with the aim of better interoperability with native Windows software. It includes: MSYS2-shell and MinGW-w64 Win32 shell & MinGW-w64 Win64 shell.

Comment: @sancho.s The AUR (arch linux) packages you have posted the links of means that you are able to build them on Arch linux when you satisfy the building dependencies - which for *mingw-w64-agrum* are: mingw-w64-crt (mingw-w64-crt-bin, mingw-w64-crt-git), mingw-w64-cmake (make).  AUR package (PKGBUILD) only defines how the source code is compiled (https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=mingw-w64-agrum).  You could try to compile the package your self based on the PKGBUILD on the MSYS2 env.